# Scala Filtering List of Case Class

Tags: scala, case-class

Suppose you have a case class like below

```
case class Fruit(name: String, color: String, price: Double){
}
```

and you also have list of case class

```
val Fruits = List
(Fruit("Apple", "red", 3.00), Fruit ("Banana", "yellow", 4.99))

How do you filter based on name?
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Question is fine but what is also important to share analysis/(mis)understanding made thus far.

Answer (score 5):

Use the `filter` function to select the `name` attribute of the case class `Fruit`

```
scala> Fruits.filter(fruit => fruit.name == "Apple")
val res0: List[Fruit] = List(Fruit(Apple,red,3.0))
```

Answer (score 5):

`List` has a `filter` method.

```
case class Fruit(name: String, color: String, price: Double)

val Fruits = List(Fruit("Apple", "red", 3.00), Fruit ("Banana", "yellow", 4.99))

Fruits.filter(_.name == "Apple")
```